# Tensorflow: how to detect audio direction

Tags: tensorflow, audio, direction

I have a task: **to determine the sound source location**.

I had some experience working with `tensorflow`, creating predictions on some simple features and datasets. I assume that for this task, there would be necessary to analyze the sound frequences and probably other related data on training and then prediction steps. The sound goes from the headset, so human ear is able to detect the direction.

*1) Did somebody already perform that?* (unfortunately couldn't find any similar project)
*2) What kind of caveats could I meet while trying to achieve that?*
*3) Am I able to do that using this technology approach? Are there any other sound processing frameworks / technologies / open source projects that could help me ?*

I am asking that here, since my research on google, github, stackoverflow didn't show me any relevant results on that specific topic, so any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically done with more traditional DSP with multiple sensors. You might want to look into time difference of arrival(TDOA) and direction of arrival(DOA). Algorithms such as GCC-PHAT and MUSIC will be helpful.

Issues that you might encounter are: DOA accuracy is function of the direct to reverberant ratio of the source, i.e. the more reverberant the environment the harder it is to determine the source location.

Also you might want to consider the number of location dimensions you want to resolve. A point in 3D space is much more difficult than a direction relative to the sensors

Using ML as an approach to this is not entirely without merit but you will have to consider what it is you would be learning, i.e. you probably don't want to learn the test rooms reverberant properties but instead the sensors spatial properties.

Comment: Can I mention the specific detail that there is no sensors, it's the in app sound which I want to process. Is it changing some aspects of the answer you gave me ? Thank you

Comment: The audio was presumably captured from a microphone which would be considered a sensor.